# how to hide tab bar in the view controller that embedded in the navigation stack in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

[image]

I have an InvoiceVC in the second tab bar ( tab Bar index : 1 ) like the picture above. if the table view cell is tapped, I need to segue to the InvoiceDetailVC like the picture below

[image]

as you can see in the InvoiceDetailVC,  there is no tab bar in the bottom of the InvoiceDetailVC, I mean that tab that has red badge in the bottom. I need remove that tab bar.

I have tried to use present modally instead of push show segue. But the problem is, there is no back button to back to InvoiceVC

so what should I do ?

[image]

Comment: In your destination controller attribute inspector check the box hide bottom bar on push.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use in `prepareforsegue` while pushing and set `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` to true to hide the tabbar on destination view controller.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "InvoiceVC") {
        let indexPath: IndexPath? = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let destViewController = segue.destination as? InvoiceVC
        destViewController?.recipeName = recipes[indexPath?.row ?? 0]
        destViewController?.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
    }
}
```